# How to create an empty EventHandler in C#?

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

I want to create an EventHandler without any methods attached to it. It's important to do it on the runtime rather than on compile time. Later on I can add the methods then invoke the event.

```
EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler(); // Compiler error

if(some_condition)
{
    eventHandler += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some condition is true");
    };
}
else
{
    eventHandler += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("some condition is false");
    };
}

eventHandler?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

I'm having problems with only the first line of code. It doesn't let me create a new EventHandler with no parameters. But if I add an emtpy lambda, it does.

```
EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler((sender, e) => { });
```

It looks ugly to have an empty lambda, but if I remove it, I can't compile the program. How should I initialize the eventHandler?

Comment: Why is it necessary?  A delegate is method. You don't instantiate a method

Comment: I just want to create an event or event handler at run time. By using the += operator on an event handler, I can assign more actions to that handler, then later invoke them. I have to initialize the eventHandler or I will get a compiler error. @MickyD

Comment: Again I ask why do you want to `eventHandler = new EventHandler(); `?  You can't.  Just do `event EventHandler eventHandler;`  No `new` required

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to instanciate and empty `EventHandler` instance. The usual way would be to declare an `event` in your class like below:

```
class Example
{
    event EventHandler Event;

    void AddHandlerAndInvoke(bool condition)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
           Event += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("true");
        }
        else
        {
            Event += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("true");
        }

        Event?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This will create an `event` than can be will call (*be handled by*) `EventHandler` instances.

Comment: This would be fine for me if I wanted to create the event in compile time, but I want to create it at run time. More specificly, I want to create n amount of event handlers. Is there any way to do it? @ChristianHeld

Comment: @JanosNagy you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how delegates and event handlers work